# Google Web Map checkboxes work in Firefox & Chrome, but do not function in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-maps, firefox

My google map website is working well in Firefox and Chrome, however the checkbox functionality is NOT working in IE. Can someone tell me why, I need to deploy this ASAP and having issues with IE. My client uses IE 8. Thanks for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet  -->    
<html>
  <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="included.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <Title>Web Map Tool</Title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a").click(function(event){
              alert("Something went wrong - talk to your developer!!!");
              event.preventDefault();
            });
          });
        </script>
        <div data-role="page"> 
    <div data-role="header"> 
      <h1>Google map Web Viewer Tool</h1>   
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <br>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br> 
        <script type="text/javascript"
          src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<yourkey>&sensor=false">
        </script>
        <br>
        <script>
    var map;                //this is the reference to your map
    var markersArray = [];  //this is an array holding the markers plotted on the map
    var infoWindow;         //this is the reference to a reuseable InfoWindow
    // harcoded places
    // on the form [name, lat, lng, category, content] 
    var places = [ 
        ['Group1', 47.364237, -92.690690, 3, '<h2>Group (-11)</h2>'], 
        ['Group2', 43.711833, -95.719528, 1, '<h2>Group (4)</h2>'], 
        ['Group3', 44.947385, -92.854821, 2, '<h2>Group (12)</h2>'], 
        ['Group4', 45.899306, -91.521083, 4, '<h2>Group (-4)</h2>'], 
        ['Group5', 45.223620, -91.127480, 1, '<h2>Group (3)</h2>'], 
        ['Group6', 46.448371, -90.166895, 2, '<h2>Group (7)</h2>'], 
        ['Group7', 40.471315, -107.580322, 2, '<h2>Group (1)</h2>'], 
        ['Group8', 38.208628, -104.574672, 1, '<h2>Group (5)</h2>'], 
        ['Group9', 39.623084, -104.452554, 2, '<h2>Group (10)</h2>'], 
        ['Group10', 33.186694, -101.407897, 3, '<h2>Group (-6)</h2>'], 
        ['Group11', 32.210741, -103.262702, 1, '<h2>Group (6)</h2>'], 
        ['Group12', 33.991050, -103.858130, 2, '<h2>Group (11)</h2>'], 

    ];


    //just for fun, different icons for each category
    //I thought you may wanted to show different icons
    //here just some of the "official" google marker icons
    var icons = [
        'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/red-circle.png', //Red
        'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/ylw-circle.png', //Yellow
        'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/grn-circle.png', //Green
        'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/blu-circle.png', //Blue

    ];

    // center map in middle of Nebraska
    var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(40.658014, -99.439275);

    //create the map
    function createMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: mapCenter,
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
            zoomControl: true,
            streetViewControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
            }
        });

        //create a global infowindow to show content
        //set a maxwidth of 300 pixel
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            maxWidth: 300,
            map: map
        });
    }

    function initMarkers() {
        for (var i=0; i<places.length; i++) {
            var place=places[i];

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(place[1], place[2],place[3]),
                map: map,

                //set icon, category as icons index 
                //outcomment this line if you just want to show the defuult icon
                icon : icons[place[3]],

                //add data from places to the marker
                title : place[0],
                category: place[3],
                content: place[4]
            });



            //add the marker to the markersArray, used to hide/show markers
            markersArray.push(marker);

            //create a click event that shows the infowindow when a marker is clicked
            //the infowindow get latlng and content from the marker
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infoWindow.setPosition(this.position);
                infoWindow.setContent(this.content);
                infoWindow.open(map);
            });
        }
    }

    //show / hide markers based on category
    //if category is 0, show all markers
    function showMarkersByCategory(category) {
        for (var i=0; i<markersArray.length; i++) {
            if ((category==0) || (markersArray[i].category==category)) {
                markersArray[i].setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }
    function initialize() {
        createMap();
        initMarkers();

    //init the select box where you show/hide the markers per category
        var checkbox=document.getElementById('checkbox');
        checkbox.onclick = function() {
            for (var i=0; i<markersArray.length; i++) {
                markersArray[i].setVisible(false);
            }
        var checkedBoxes = $('#checkbox > input:checkbox:checked');
            for (var i = 0; i < checkedBoxes.length; i++){
            var category = checkedBoxes[i].value;
            showMarkersByCategory(category);
            }
        }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head> 
    <body>
    <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:800px;float:left;clear:none;"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 5px; top: 20px; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">   
            <br>
            <form id="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="1"><b>Group 1</b>&nbsp
            <input type="checkbox" name="group2" value="2"><b>Group 2</b>&nbsp
            <input type="checkbox" name="group3" value="3"><b>Group 3</b>&nbsp
            <input type="checkbox" name="group4" value="4"><b>Group 4</b>&nbsp&nbsp
            </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes I did, however I am no expert I never use IE. This is what I found: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.1; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Tue, 24 Sep 2013 16:43:03 UTC


Message: '1' is null or not an object
Line: 146
Char: 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have "hanging" commas in your code (commas after the last entry of your arrays).  That causes problems in older version of IE (they add an extra null entry to the array).  Remove them.

i.e. change:

```
var places = [ 
        ['Group1', 47.364237, -92.690690, 3, '<h2>Group (-11)</h2>'], 
        ['Group2', 43.711833, -95.719528, 1, '<h2>Group (4)</h2>'], 
        ['Group3', 44.947385, -92.854821, 2, '<h2>Group (12)</h2>'], 
        ['Group4', 45.899306, -91.521083, 4, '<h2>Group (-4)</h2>'], 
        ['Group5', 45.223620, -91.127480, 1, '<h2>Group (3)</h2>'], 
        ['Group6', 46.448371, -90.166895, 2, '<h2>Group (7)</h2>'], 
        ['Group7', 40.471315, -107.580322, 2, '<h2>Group (1)</h2>'], 
        ['Group8', 38.208628, -104.574672, 1, '<h2>Group (5)</h2>'], 
        ['Group9', 39.623084, -104.452554, 2, '<h2>Group (10)</h2>'], 
        ['Group10', 33.186694, -101.407897, 3, '<h2>Group (-6)</h2>'], 
        ['Group11', 32.210741, -103.262702, 1, '<h2>Group (6)</h2>'], 
        ['Group12', 33.991050, -103.858130, 2, '<h2>Group (11)</h2>'], // <<-- remove comma here 

    ];
```

To:

```
var places = [ 
        ['Group1', 47.364237, -92.690690, 3, '<h2>Group (-11)</h2>'], 
        ['Group2', 43.711833, -95.719528, 1, '<h2>Group (4)</h2>'], 
        ['Group3', 44.947385, -92.854821, 2, '<h2>Group (12)</h2>'], 
        ['Group4', 45.899306, -91.521083, 4, '<h2>Group (-4)</h2>'], 
        ['Group5', 45.223620, -91.127480, 1, '<h2>Group (3)</h2>'], 
        ['Group6', 46.448371, -90.166895, 2, '<h2>Group (7)</h2>'], 
        ['Group7', 40.471315, -107.580322, 2, '<h2>Group (1)</h2>'], 
        ['Group8', 38.208628, -104.574672, 1, '<h2>Group (5)</h2>'], 
        ['Group9', 39.623084, -104.452554, 2, '<h2>Group (10)</h2>'], 
        ['Group10', 33.186694, -101.407897, 3, '<h2>Group (-6)</h2>'], 
        ['Group11', 32.210741, -103.262702, 1, '<h2>Group (6)</h2>'], 
        ['Group12', 33.991050, -103.858130, 2, '<h2>Group (11)</h2>'] // <<-- remove comma here

    ];
```

Comment: Wow that is amazing, thank you for you help.. I have been pasting in more and more markers so I must have missed that. I will see what happens. Thanks again

Comment: There may be others, fix all of them (the icons array has the same issue).  It doesn't matter in Chrome or Firefox, but breaks older versions of IE (I think it is addressed in the latest version)